# How I can rearrange the last element of an array to the first place?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in javascript:

```
shapeToolsTarget: Array(4)
0: {id: 20, name: "Background", type: "shape"}
1: {id: 21, name: "BorderColor", type: "shape"}
2: {id: 22, name: "BorderWeight", type: "shape"}
3: {id: 3, name: "Paste", type: "text"}
```

How I can rearrange the last element of an array to the first place? Like that:

```
shapeToolsTarget: Array(4)
0: {id: 3, name: "Paste", type: "text"}
1: {id: 20, name: "Background", type: "shape"}
2: {id: 21, name: "BorderColor", type: "shape"}
3: {id: 22, name: "BorderWeight", type: "shape"}
```

Comment: Did you tried something that you can show us? Then we can help

Comment: @Calvin Nunes I tried array_shift() function but it did not bring results..

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

> The `unshift()` method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.
>
> The `pop()` method removes the **last** element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

```js
var items = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
console.log(items);

items.unshift(items.pop());
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have 4 elements instead of 3 and i got 
0: {id: 22, name: "BorderWeightComponent", type: "shape"}
1: {id: 3, name: "Paste", type: "text"}
2: {id: 20, name: "Background", type: "shape"}
3: {id: 21, name: "Border", type: "shape"}

Comment: The number and type of element in the array does not matter, I've added a description to clarify how both methods work. Just do `shapeToolsTarget.unshift(shapeToolsTarget.pop());`.

Comment: Okay! But I got this element on the 2nd place! Instead of first..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) & [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) array methods for this like:

- `pop()` removes the last element from the array.
- `unshift(value)` adds the `value` to the beginning of the array.

```js
let shapeToolsTarget = [
{id: 20, name: "Background", type: "shape"},
{id: 21, name: "BorderColor", type: "shape"},
{id: 22, name: "BorderWeight", type: "shape"},
{id: 3, name: "Paste", type: "text"}];

shapeToolsTarget.unshift(shapeToolsTarget.pop())

console.log(shapeToolsTarget)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I got that one using ur code 0: {id: 22, name: "BorderWeightComponent", type: "shape"} 1: {id: 3, name: "Paste", type: "text"} 2: {id: 20, name: "Background", type: "shape"} 3: {id: 21, name: "Border", type: "shape"} It`s on the 2nd place..

Comment: Code updated. Please try again.